# Animate camera horizontally three.js

Tags: three.js, gsap

I'm doing a camera animation in Three.js with GSAP, I'm trying to animate it horizontally like the panning in a film.
Anyone knows if is possible to animate the pan in orbit controls or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `OrbitControls` and you want to manually animate a pan, you have to animate the camera position and `OrbitControls.target` which represents the focus point of the controls. The relevant code for the controls is:

```js
gsap.to( controls.target, {
    duration: 2,
    x: 10,
    onUpdate: function() {
        controls.update();
    }
} );
```

Full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kerpm61q/

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I looking for!!